# Apache axis 401 unauthorized error

Tags: soap, jax-ws, axis

I am using axis client to invoke a SOAP service.

```
_call.invoke(new java.lang.Object[] {orderInfo_MT});
```

I am getting exception in the execution of the above code..

```
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:744)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
```

This piece of code used to work fine earlier, not sure why it breaks now.
We had an expired certificate and so replaced the expired certificate with a valid one. But I am not sure whether is any connection between the new certificate and this issue.

Can someone provide some inputs on this issue ?

Updating the additonal logs from the catalina logs..

> Padded plaintext after DECRYPTION:  len = 32 0000: 01 00 B2 B9 73 FE
>   93 14   A5 3F DD 37 99 C6 40 74  ....s....?.7..@t 0010: DE E9 77 AB F2
>   E5 09 09   09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09  ..w............. http-9080-1, RECV
>   TLSv1 ALERT:  warning, close_notify http-9080-1, called
>   closeInternal(false) http-9080-1, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  warning,
>   description = close_notify Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len =
>   32 0000: 01 00 DA F5 38 5F 4D A5   ED 1B FF 8A 59 8C 6B F3 
>   ....8_M.....Y.k. 0010: 68 14 8B D4 09 61 09 09   09 09 09 09 09 09 09
>   09  h....a.......... http-9080-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 32 [Raw
>   write]: length = 37 0000: 15 03 01 00 20 8C B0 D8   D3 B9 56 50 76 8E
>   C0 FB  .... .....VPv... 0010: 4E D7 37 86 69 BB 8C 72   11 AF 3E A7 1F
>   CE 71 58  N.7.i..r..>...qX 0020: AE 14 8A 9C 9B
>   ..... http-9080-1, called closeSocket(selfInitiated) http-9080-1,
>   called close() http-9080-1, called closeInternal(true)
>
> AxisFault  faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP  faultSubcode:
>   faultString: (401)Unauthorized  faultActor:   faultNode:
>   faultDetail:      {}:return code:  401
>
> {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HttpErrorCode:401

(401)Unauthorized
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:744)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at org.worldbank.eservices.internal_order_processing.OrderInformation_MIBindingStub.orderInformation_MI(OrderInformation_MIBindingStub.java:182)
    at org.worldbank.ecommerce.service.backend.PIIntegration.invokePIWebservice(PIIntegration.java:75)
    at org.worldbank.ecommerce.service.backend.PIIntegration.invokePIWebservice(PIIntegration.java:97)
    at org.worldbank.eservicesadaptors.webservices.services.OrderXiPostingService.OrderXiPostingServiceSoapBindingImpl.eServicesOrderXiPosting(OrderXiPostingServiceSoapBindingImpl.java:45)
    at org.worldbank.eservicesadaptors.webservices.services.OrderXiPostingService.OrderXiPostingServiceSoapBindingSkeleton.eServicesOrderXiPosting(OrderXiPostingServiceSoapBindingSkeleton.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Try adding `-Djavax.net.debug=all` to the JAVA_OPT's when you're starting the application server (if it's an app server) or if it's a standalone jar or class pass it when starting the app. It also looks like you're missing the pertinent line saying exactly what exception it is - could you provide it?  `-Djavax.net.debug=all` will show exactly whats going on with the connection

Comment: Yes, I had it enabled, additional error information details are now included.

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this?